# How to mock the method invoked on the reponse of a mocked method

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, springmockito

I have a class

```
class A {

    @Autowired
    DbObject dbObject;

    method1 () {
        try {
            return DbObject.read("query").getItem ();
        }
        catch (NotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I have to test method1 is returning null if NotFound Exception is thrown , I will create @MockBean for DbObject in test class. How to write a when condition to mock getItem(). when(DbObject.method1("query")).thenThrow("NotFoundException") . But this wont mock the getItem method invoked on the object returned by our mock when(DbObject.method1("query")).

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to use chaining of mocked methods. declare two mocks: one for `dbObject`, and another one for returned result from `dbObject.read("query")` (let's call that `dbObjectQueryResult`).

```
when(dbObject.read("query")).thenReturn(dbObjectQueryResult);
when(dbObjectQueryResult.getItem()).thenThrow(new NotFoundException("test"))
```